# Python nested while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, nested-loops

Being a beginner with Python (Python 3.x), I was trying and getting my hands dirty with the while loop, when I ran into a small snag - no doubt due to my inexperience with the language - the code runs in a continuous loop!

The code is as follows :

```
n=0
while (n<len(txt)) :
    while (n<5) :
        #t = txt[n].value
        #print(t)
        n=n+1
        print(n)
```

In the program, n is a control variable. txt is a list which stores the values extracted from my excel sheet. The aim of the program is to loop through the contents of each cell in the column of the sheet (represented by the list txt).
However, due to some silly mistake in this code, Python seems to run into an endless loop. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
P.S. the 5 in the inner loop is just representative of a number I will loop through again.

Comment: If len(txt)>5, the program cannot jump out the first while. Because the max n (added at the second while) is 5.

Comment: thank you very much! :)
that worked perfectly well!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work perfectly fine now :

> ```
> n=0 
> while (n<len(txt)) :
>   if n==50:
>     break
>   while (n<50) :
>     #t = txt[n].value
>     #print(t)
>     n=n+1
>     print(n)
> ```

Thanks ybdesire! (y)
One small question thought - why does the Spyder editor not return back to the next console command line, some times, despite having finished execution ?

Comment: Make you Spyder question a new, separate question, with an example that dependably fails as you describe.